# Need Help Reading Some C#

Tags: c#

The code is:

```
 private static void loadAccounts()
 {
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader("accounts.txt"))
    {
       string line = null;
       while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
       {
         String[] details = line.Split('\t');
         accounts.Add(details[0].Substring(6) +
                      ":" + details[1].Substring(10));
       }
    }
}
```

What should the text file contain/How should the contense be formatted.
i've tried:
Username:Password
Username   /t     Password

but get errors

the error is:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: startIndex cannot be larger than length of string.
>   at System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
>       at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex, Int32 length)
>       at System.String.Substring(Int32 startIndex)
>       at Test.Program.loadAccounts() in 
>       c:\Users\Documents\SharpDevelopProjects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 148
>       at Test.Program.Main(String[] args) in 
>       c:\Users\Documents\SharpDevelopProjects\Test\Test\Program.cs:line 26

Comment: `\t` is a tabulation. i.e. Tab key

Comment: Your question title doesn't says much. Please refer [How do I write a good title?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: SO isn't a website for solving coding quizzes, you should know what the textfile should contain and what you want it to do

Comment: The error reads:
(even why i try sepperating username and password with tabs):

Comment: Debug inside of your code and check for the length of the string-array "details" BEFORE you reach THIS part of your code: "details[0].Substring(6)"

Answer (score 0):

Weird code.

This line splits a line in the text file on a tab-character, e.g. "Username *(imagine a tab here)* Password"

```
 String[] details = line.Split('\t');
```

This line discards the first 6 characters of the username element (details[0]), adds a colon, discards the first 10 characters of the password element (details[1]) and concatenates it into a single string.

```
 accounts.Add(details[0].Substring(6) + ":" + details[1].Substring(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

All lines in the text file should have:
Min user Name length = 6
Min Password length = 10
I would also replace the '\t' with something like ' ' or '-'

- MyNameIs-MyPasswordIsTheFollowing1
- MyNameIs-MyPasswordIsTheFollowing2
- MyNameIs-MyPasswordIsTheFollowing3
- MyNameIs-MyPasswordIsTheFollowing4

Comment: Oh i see ^_^ seems to work now that i changed them both too 1, not sure how well its working but no errors, thank you very much :D

Comment: -Realising i will have to do some editing for it too make any real purpose

Comment: Jordan if this solve your Problem than mark this as answer :-)

Comment: you can also ask for the string length before cutting!